# Uncaught TypeError: .indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, indexof

I am new to JavaScript and I'm getting an **error** as below.

> Uncaught TypeError: time.indexOf is not a function

Gee, I really thought indexOf() really was a function.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    var timeofday = new Date().getHours() + (new Date().getMinutes()) / 60;
    document.getElementById("oset").innerHTML = timeD2C(timeofday);
</script>


<script>
 function timeD2C(time) { // Converts 11.5 (decimal) to 11:30 (colon)
    var pos = time.indexOf('.');
    var hrs = time.substr(1, pos - 1);
    var min = (time.substr(pos, 2)) * 60;

    if (hrs > 11) {
        hrs = (hrs - 12) + ":" + min + " PM";
    } else {
        hrs += ":" + min + " AM";
    }
    return hrs;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is indeed a function - of a valid object - meaning `time` isn't a valid object.  Make sure time exists, log it inside the `timeD2C` function call.

Comment: Why do you think a number has an `indexOf` function?

Comment: Your code is mixing strings and numbers. You need to be careful that you are using the correct type when performing each operation.

Answer (score 34):

Basically `indexOf()` is a method belongs to string(array object also), But while calling the function you are passing a number, try to cast it to a string and pass it.

```
document.getElementById("oset").innerHTML = timeD2C(timeofday + "");
```

```js
 var timeofday = new Date().getHours() + (new Date().getMinutes()) / 60;




 function timeD2C(time) { // Converts 11.5 (decimal) to 11:30 (colon)
    var pos = time.indexOf('.');
    var hrs = time.substr(1, pos - 1);
    var min = (time.substr(pos, 2)) * 60;

    if (hrs > 11) {
        hrs = (hrs - 12) + ":" + min + " PM";
    } else {
        hrs += ":" + min + " AM";
    }
    return hrs;
}
alert(timeD2C(timeofday+""));
```

---

And it is good to do the string conversion inside your function definition,

```
function timeD2C(time) { 
  time = time + "";
  var pos = time.indexOf('.');
```

So that the code flow won't break at times when devs forget to pass a string into this function.

Comment: Casting to string would better be placed _inside_ the function – that way, it won’t throw errors should it be called with a number from somewhere else for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.  I added the time=time+"" and the problem went away.  JavaScript is so liberal when dealing with stings and numbers that it's easy to forget that a number can't always be treated as a string.

Comment: I think a clean approach will be converting to String like `time  = String(time)`

Comment: @TerryO, please accept this answer if it worked. This question is marked without an accepted answer until then.

Answer (score 8):

Convert timeofday to string to use `indexOf`

```
var timeofday = new Date().getHours() + (new Date().getMinutes()) / 60;
console.log(typeof(timeofday)) // for testing will log number
function timeD2C(time) { // Converts 11.5 (decimal) to 11:30 (colon)
    var pos = time.indexOf('.');
    var hrs = time.substr(1, pos - 1);
    var min = (time.substr(pos, 2)) * 60;

    if (hrs > 11) {
        hrs = (hrs - 12) + ":" + min + " PM";
    } else {
        hrs += ":" + min + " AM";
    }
    return hrs;
}
 // "" for typecasting to string
 document.getElementById("oset").innerHTML = timeD2C(""+timeofday);
```

[Test Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cjn0v9z4/2/)

**Solution 2**

use `toString()` to convert to `string`

```
document.getElementById("oset").innerHTML = timeD2C(timeofday.toString());
```

[jsfiddle with toString()](https://jsfiddle.net/cjn0v9z4/3/)

Answer (score 7):

I was getting `e.data.indexOf is not a function` error, after debugging it, I found that it was actually a `TypeError`, which meant, `indexOf()` being a function is applicable to strings, so I typecasted the data like the following and then used the `indexOf()` method to make it work

```
e.data.toString().indexOf('<stringToBeMatchedToPosition>')
```

Not sure if my answer was accurate to the question, but yes shared my opinion as i faced a similar kind of situation.

Comment: Exactly my issue. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error recently using a javascript library which changes the parameters of a function based on conditions.

You can test an object to see if it has the function. I would only do this in scenarios where you don't control what is getting passed to you.

```
if( param.indexOf != undefined ) {
   // we have a string or other object that 
   // happens to have a function named indexOf
}
```

You can test this in your browser console:

```
> (3).indexOf == undefined;
true

> "".indexOf == undefined;
false
```