# JavaScript: BannerPlugin.js results in error: str.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript

In my React app, executing `npm run build` results in:

```
Module parse failed: ...\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
```

So according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40763389/6761698), the first line `#!/usr/bin/env node` in `npm-cli.js` was the issue. To resolve this, I could make use of BannerPlugin ([docs](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/blob/master/src/content/plugins/banner-plugin.md)), which I did:

Location: `webpack.config.prod.js` / `webpack.config.dev.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: "#!/usr/bin/env node",
      raw: true
    })
  ],
  ...
};
```

Now, executing `npm run build` again results in:

```
...\node_modules\webpack\lib\BannerPlugin.js:9
    if(str.indexOf("\n") < 0) return "/*! " + str + " */";
           ^

TypeError: str.indexOf is not a function
  at wrapComment (...\node_modules\webpack\lib\BannerPlugin.js:9:9)
  ...
```

Reading the comments in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483151/uncaught-typeerror-indexof-is-not-a-function), I concluded that `str` is not a valid object. **How would one resolve this issue without having to modify** `BannerPlugin.js`**, or bypass the use of BannerPlugin entirely?**

**Edit 1:** Here is the entire [webpack.config.dev.js](https://pastebin.com/J5Hd1C9J) and [webpack.config.prod.js](https://pastebin.com/fY2x16kE) as a Pastebin. The version of the webpack should be "`webpack@1.14.0`" as found in the webpack `package.json` (`npm list webpack` did not work).

**Edit 2:** I have bypassed the use of BannerPlugin [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198010/resolving-unexpected-character-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Why do you use "raw: true" ?

Comment: From the docs: if true, banner will not be wrapped in a comment

Comment: Can you provide the whole config file? And what version of webpack you are using?

Comment: @Littlee I have updated the question

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old now but just found it myself so for anyone else I suspect you have the new parameter layout with an old version of BannerPlugin.  For webpack 1 it took banner as the first parameter, not named.  From 2 or 3 it takes an object.

For you this would be:

```
new webpack.BannerPlugin('#!/usr/bin/env node', { raw: true })
```

Webpack 3 would be what you have:

```
new webpack.BannerPlugin({ banner: '#!/usr/bin/env node', raw: true })
```