# Firebase update existing value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase and I want to update a text in a note that the user created.

```
const [updateInput, setupdateInput] = useState('');

const handleUpdate = (id) => {
  db.collection('notes').doc(id).update({
    details: updateInput,
  });
};
...
<form noValidate autoComplete='off' onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
  <TextField
    onChange={(e) => setupdateInput(e.target.value)}
    defaultValue={note.details}
  />
  <Button type='submit'>Update</Button>
</form>;
```

I want to give a chance to edit a text in a note but the firestore database doesn't update.

Comment: "It doesn't work." doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: It doesnt update my firestore database. Ive got an error "Uncaught TypeError: u.indexOf is not a function"

Comment: In that case, these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483151/uncaught-typeerror-indexof-is-not-a-function) will help, right?

Comment: What should be the `id` of your `notes` document?